# How to configure mercurial to push with OSX 10.4

Tags: macos, mercurial

When attempting to push changes to bitbucket.org I receive an error "abort: authorization failed". I have configured my ~//.hgrc file to the following

```
[web]
cacerts = /etc/hg-ca-roots.pem
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false
```

I know my login credential are correct because they work perfectly on bitbucket.org. I am able to pull content just fine and can even use the $ hg outgoing command with no problems. What am I doing wrong?

```
computer:~/desktop/sinebase chris$ hg push --debug
pushing to https://bitbucket.org/
using https://bitbucket.org/
sending between command
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
sending capabilities command
capabilities: changegroupsubset stream lookup pushkey unbundle=HG10GZ,HG10BZ,HG10UN branchmap
sending heads command
searching for changes
common changesets up to fa4942e93eea
sending branchmap command
1 changesets found
list of changesets:
5fbc99565b8647652145fcd6ac8c48b900418701
bundling: 0 changesets
bundling: 0 changesets
bundling: 0 changesets
bundling: 1 changesets
bundling: 0/1 manifests (0.00%)
bundling: 0/1 manifests (0.00%)
bundling: 0/1 manifests (0.00%)
bundling: 1/1 manifests (100.00%)
bundling: app/urls.py 0/1 files (0.00%)
bundling: app/urls.py 0/1 files (0.00%)
bundling: app/urls.py 0/1 files (0.00%)
bundling: app/urls.py 0/1 files (0.00%)
sending unbundle command
sending 375 bytes
sending: 0 kb
sending: 0 kb
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: ******
password: 
http auth: user ******, password *********
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
sending: 0 kb
sending: 0 kb
http auth: user ******, password *********
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
sending: 1 kb
sending: 1 kb
http auth: user ******, password *********
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
sending: 1 kb
sending: 1 kb
http auth: user ******, password *********
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
sending: 1 kb
sending: 1 kb
http auth: user ******, password *********
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
sending: 2 kb
sending: 2 kb
http auth: user ******, password *********
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
sending: 2 kb
sending: 2 kb
abort: authorization failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not a private repo you'd be able to pull and do outgoing without authenticating, so it's still possible your credentials are wrong.  Try using `--debug` next time.

Comment: Are the authorization credentials the same for pushing as they are to log in on bitbucket.org? If so, then my credentials are correct.

Comment: Hrm.  Can you try pushing to the ssh URL?  Every bitbucket repo has both.  You can do it it like `ssh clone ssh://....` and you can find the SSH URL for your repo on the bitbucket repo page.

Comment: I tried: hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/<USERNAME>/<REPOSITORY>      The output is "abort: no suitable response from remote hg!"